# Permission Issues in Creating Cloud Storage Bucket with Cloud KMS Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-kms

I have setup a CMEK(Customer Managed Encryption Key) key ring in GCP Cloud KMS

Then I am trying to create a new cloud storage bucket with GCP Cloud KMS Key.

Getting an error on the console

```
The service-XXXXX345XXXX@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com service account does not have the 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter' role.Verify that the service account has permission to encrypt/decrypt with the selected key.

You need permissions for this action.
Required permission(s):

projects/test/locations/europe-west2/keyRings/integrations-test-data/cryptoKeys/integrations-test-data
All of cloudkms.cryptoKeys.getIamPolicy and cloudkms.cryptoKeys.setIamPolicy
```

### Questions

1. Where does the service account belongs ?
2. How can I add permissions to this service account to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

### What is service-XXXXX345XXXX@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com ?

`XXXXX345XXXX` after `service-` is identifier number for your project.

You can verify the same identifier using

```
➜ gcloud projects list                                                   
PROJECT_ID                   NAME                         PROJECT_NUMBER
test                         test                         XXXXX345XXXX
```

### How does this service accounts gets created ?

> Some Google Cloud services have Google-managed service accounts that
> allow the services to access your resources. These service accounts
> are known as service agents. If an API requires a service agent, then
> Google creates the service agent after you activate and use the API.

Read more about Service Agents here

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents

Read about CMEK and understand roles required for cloud storage using CMEK

https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/customer-managed-encryption-keys

### How to add permissions ?

```
gcloud storage service-agent --project=PROJECT_STORING_OBJECTS --authorize-cmek=KEY_RESOURCE
```

Note : Make sure to have `cloudkms.cryptoKeys.setIamPolicy` role to your user to apply above operation.

Reference :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-managed-keys#service-agent-access